# What happens to a non-captured R environment or object?

Tags: r, memory-management, namespaces, garbage-collection

I am reading [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) by Hadley Wickham, chapter on environments. Let's run the following code:

```
f <- function() {
    e = environment()
}
str(f())
#<environment: 0x0000000011fdaa80> 
str(ee <- f())
#<environment: 0x0000000011fda7a8>
```

I can access the second environment by `ee`. But what happens to the first? Is it deleted instantly, or perhaps marked for `gc()` but still exists? Can I access it somehow (by memory address, maybe)?

Going even further, will the behaviour be the same if I return some "regular" R object? Say, for `g <- function() runif(1)`?

Comment: It will be marked for deletion. That means you can no longer access it from within R, and the gc will free the memory next on the next sweep.  You might find your questions answered by http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html

Comment: I should have guessed to look a bit forward in the book. Thanks!